# Java.Почему в c записывается только целая часть?

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String a=reader.readLine();
int b=Integer.parseInt(a);
double c=b/4;
// double d=c-(int)c;
System.out.print(c);
```

К примеру при вводе числа 13 он выдает ответ 3.0

Comment: потому что при делении целых чисел результат получается целым.

Comment: ... и судя по количеству подобных вопросов, это ошибка разработчиков стандарта.

Answer (score 16):

Потому что `b` - `int` и 4 тоже `int`
Строка `double c = b / 4;` работает так:

```
double c = (double)(b / 4);
```

Сперва происходит целочисленное деление, а затем приведение к `double`;

Чтобы деление было не целочисленным напишите:

```
double c = b / 4.0;
```

В этом случае `b` приведется к `double` всё будет корректно.