# конвертирует в целое число

Tags: c++-cli

```
byte s = sim[5];
    double val = System::Convert::ToDouble((s*5)/255);
    return Convert::ToString(val);
```

В результате получается 3, а должно быть 3,25 ну или же если 3 то 3,00
почему не верно конвертирует, нужно указать формат ?

Comment: Деление целых чисел имеет целочисленный результат. Если вы конвертируете целое число в Double, откуда появиться дробной части?

Comment: Согласен, а как будет правильно записать что бы появилась дробная часть?

Comment: Сконвертируйте в Double _перед_ делением, а не после него.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо работает, а не подскажете как отформатировать переменную val что бы выводило  два знака после запятой ?

Comment: @VladD  textBoxInfoPaperSensor->Text = ("%.2f",printer.Voltage());   пробую так, всеравно выводит все знаки

Comment: `string.Format`, посмотрите [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java.Почему в c записывается только целая часть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569101/java-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что деление целых чисел в C++/CLI, как и в C++, даёт целочисленный результат, отбрасывая дробную часть. Поэтому конвертация *после* деления не имеет смысла: результат деления уже является целым числом, дробная часть потеряна.

Конвертируйте в `double` *до* деления:

```
double val = (double)s*5/255;
```